# Proper way to join tables in mysql to have a single result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have a mysql database with three tables that has three table I am trying to retrieve rows of data from `content` based on a condition on data `phpro_tag_types`

The structures of the tables is like so

phpro_tag_types

```
tag_type_id | tag_type_name
  <pk>
```

phpro_tag_targets

```
tag_target_id | tag_id | sub_tag_id | tag_target_name | tag_type_id
    <pk>      |  <FK>  |    <FK>    |                 |    <FK>
```

content

```
   content_id | tag_target_id | bunch of other things|
    <pk>      |    <fk>       |
```

The relationships between the table is like so

```
content.tag_target_id : phpro_tag_targets.tag_target_id 
      1  :  m   //each tag_target_id is in content once 
                //and phpro_tag_targets many times   

phpro_tag_targets.tag_type_id : phpro_tag_types.tag_type_id
                             M: 1   // there is many occurrences of tag_type_id 
   //in phpro_tag_targets and one occurrence in of tag_type_id in phpro_tag_type
```

(I hope I have explained this thoroughly enough using the correct terms if not I apologize, clearly I am still kind of green with this)

Now I have a SQL query that looks like this

```
SELECT *
FROM phpro_tag_types types
INNER JOIN phpro_tag_targets targets ON types.tag_type_id=targets.tag_type_id
INNER JOIN content c ON targets.tag_target_id = c.tag_target_id
WHERE types.tag_type_id=14
ORDER BY update_time DESC
```

Now this query works however not exactly quite as I intended. The problem is the resulting array that is returned has multiple instance of the same piece of content ie. a single `content_id` (I believe because the same `tag_target_id` exists in `phpro_tag_targets` multiple times)  however I would only like the results array to only contain unique `content_id`'s as this is the data I am actually outputting to users.

As a side note putting `Distinct` into the query also doesn't seem to work as there is no way to only make sure `content` is `DISTINCT` (at least I could find)

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I am kind of lost on how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I am trying to retrieve rows of data from content based on a condition on data* `phpro_tag_types`"

Assuming you are trying to fetch fields of `content`. What about following `IN()` sub-query

```
SELECT *
FROM content c
WHERE tag_target_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT tag_target_id
    FROM phpro_tag_types types
    INNER JOIN phpro_tag_targets targets ON types.tag_type_id=targets.tag_type_id
    WHERE types.tag_type_id=14
)
ORDER BY update_time DESC;
```

BTW,

> *"As a side note putting Distinct into the query also doesn't seem to work as there is no way to only make sure content is DISTINCT (at least I could find)"*

`DISTINCT c.*` does not make sense?

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM phpro_tag_types types
INNER JOIN phpro_tag_targets targets ON types.tag_type_id=targets.tag_type_id
INNER JOIN content c ON targets.tag_target_id = c.tag_target_id
WHERE types.tag_type_id=14
ORDER BY update_time DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly .. as for the distint I was trying to do it on just content.content_id... but none the less i did misunderstand how it is supposed to be used thanks a ton for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There's a general trick to do a left outer join on the duplicating table in such a way that only one entry has null values and then limit the query to that row:

```
SELECT * 
FROM phpro_tag_types types 
INNER JOIN phpro_tag_targets targets ON types.tag_type_id=targets.tag_type_id 
INNER JOIN content c ON targets.tag_target_id = c.tag_target_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN phpro_tag_targets t2 on targets.tag_target_id=t2.tag_target_id
    AND t2.tag_id < targets.tag_id 
WHERE types.tag_type_id=1
    AND t2.tag_target_id IS NULL;
```

This seems a bit crazy but does work and in my experience is performant unless you're dealing with a 'very large' data set (whatever that means).

I'm not 100% sure what the semantics here are, but this query is assuming that you don't care what 'tag_id' you get, you just want to get any tag that matches the 'type_id', which looks to me to match your intent.

NOTE: this will cause duplicate column names in the '*' select, so you need to limit to `types.*, targets.*, content.*` or spell out the column names.

Comment: Hmm, interesting but wouldn't you want your `t2` reference in `HAVING` as opposed to `WHERE`? My experience has been that having a `LEFT JOIN`  and then having the left table in the `WHERE` tends to negate the `LEFT` part.

Comment: I may not fully grok the question, so apologies if I'm not responding to what you mean. The 'LEFT' means the left side of the join is always present in the result, with the 'INNER' and 'OUTER' variants determining what to do when the RHS of the join fails (no matching row) by excluding or including the row respectively. Either way, you still get the 't2' entries in the results that you do get and should be able to filter on them just fine with WHERE.

Comment: @zanerock hey this unfortunately doesn't seem to work meaning that no results at all are returned (i have both used exactly as you have written along with replacing `SELECT *` with `SELECT * types.*, targets.*, content.*`)

Comment: Hmmm... I actually did set up a small DB based on your tables, but I don't have all relevant info on your data so it may not be representative. I'm making some assumptions about the nature of the 'tag_id'. A note regarding the above solution: "IN" queries with an inner select are generally MUCH slower than even complex JOINs. If your dataset is small, it doesn't make much difference and the IN style is easier to follow. If you run into performance problems, though, provide a minimal data population showing the duplication, and we can probably get the join approach to work.